# Bounding a probability of airplane

Tags: probability, probability-theory, machine-learning

An airline has collected an i.i.d. sample of $10000$ flight reservations and figured out that in this sample $5$ percent of passengers who made a reservation did not show up for the flight.  They introduce a policy to sell $100$ tickets for a flight that can hold only $99$ passengers. Consider the following process of generating the two samples:

1. We sample $10100$ passenger show up events independently at random according to an unknown distribution $p$.
2. And then we split them into $10000$ passengers in the collected sample and 100 passengers booked for the $99$-seats flight.

Bound the probability of observing a sample of $10000$ with $95$% show ups and a $99$-seats flight with all $100$ passengers showing up by following the above sampling protocol.  If you do things right, you can get a bound of about $0.0062$.

My idea was to apply Hoeffding's inequality but i do not quite understand how to apply it in this case. I also thought about using that $P(A)\geq P(A \text{and} B)$ but i think i might have misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: Not following.  What "two samples" are you talking about?  What is a "passenger show up event"?  What is it you want to compute or estimate?

Comment: Are you aware that (good) answers can be accepted $\left(\color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$?

Answer (score 1):

Each flight is going to be an "experiment" on its own.  All you know is the $p$ you (the problem) calculated (i.e., the 5%), and that $p$ is a good approximation because of how big the survey was.

My first inclination would be to model this problem as a binomial random variable on $100$ seats.

That could theoretically be a pain in the butt, because of how the CDF is structured, but this time you only need to deal with the probability of a single event occurring...

If the problem involved complicated CDF calculations, I'd be looking at using a Central Limit theorem.

Good luck on your exam.