# bounding probability of biased coin.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a biased coin where heads have probability $p$. I flip it 10000 times and it comes up heads 5000 times. Now I wish to bound the probability that 5000 out of 10000 comes up as heads and that the next coin flip is heads, that is
$$
\mathbb{P}(5000/1000 \text{ heads and next coin flip is also heads})
$$

Clearly the two "events" are independent. I read that it can be bounded by $0.08$ (not that the bound would realistically be of much interest),  but I don't quite see how one would go about doing that. Can you apply Hoeffding's inequality?

Comment: Place a bound with what level of confidence?  There is no such thing as an absolute bound.

Comment: I guess that is the problem, there is no more context.

Comment: this is a somewhat related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478397/bounding-a-probability-of-airplane

Comment: I read it as, if the probability of heads on each coin flip is an unknown $p$ and $E$ is the event that 5000 of the first 10000 flips are heads, then the next flip is heads, what is the maximum value for the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(E \mid p)$

Answer (score 2):

In $2n$ tosses, the probability of getting *exactly* $n$ heads is given by $\binom{2n}n p^n (1 - p)^n$, just by counting all possibilities.
To get another head, you just need to multiply by $p$.
So your final probability is equal to
$$ \binom{2n}{n} p^{n+1} (1 - p)^n. $$
Plug in $n = 5000$. Note that if you want to do this on a computer/calculator, you should probably apply Stirling's formula to the Binomial to get an approximation.

Regarding absolute bounds, it's easy to see that $p(1-p) \le \tfrac14$ whenever $p \in [0,1]$. So you can upper bound this by
$$ \binom{2n}{n} 4^{-n} = \binom{2n}{n} 2^{-2n}. $$
As pointed out by @aschepler in the comments, differentiating gives an exact maximum at
$$ p = \frac{n+1}{2n+1} = \frac12 \biggl(1 + \frac1{2n+1}\biggr). $$

Comment: We can write the exact maximum probability too: Setting $\frac{d\mathbb{P}}{dp} = 0$ gives $p = \frac{n+1}{2n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler, I've added that point to the answer!